# How to find characters other than numbers, alphabetical and $ _ #?

Tags: java

I want to make a test if a variable contains special characters. I thought about `regular expression` but I m stuck : how to get all non numeric and letters ( lowercase and uppercase ) and other than $ and _ and # ?

Comment: can you share some example what you want to match exactly?

Comment: I want to test if the variable contains character different than 0 till 9 and a till z and A till Z and $ and _ and #

Comment: `!s.matches("(\\p{Alnum}|[_#$])*")` (java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex `[^0-9a-zA-Z#_$]+`

```
boolean check = str.replaceAll("[^0-9a-zA-Z#_$]+", "").length() < str.length();
```

If `true` then the input contains characters *different than 0 till 9 and a till z and A till Z and $ and _ and #*

The idea is, to replace all non numeric and letters (lowercase and uppercase) `$`, `_`, and `#` from your string, then check the length with the original string, if it is less then there are other characters else no.

It will return :

```
"Hello123#_$ )"   -> false
"Hello123_$#"     -> true
```

---

The simple solution is :

```
boolean check = str.matches("[0-9a-zA-Z#_$]+");
```

return `true`, if the input contains only *numeric and letters ( lowercase and uppercase ) and `$` and `_` and `#`* one or more time

Answer (score 1):

`str = str.replaceAll("[\\d\\p{L}]", "")` will remove all non numeric and Unicode letters (lowercase and uppercase ) from str

or use `str.matches(".*[^$_#?\\d\\p{L}].*")` to find if there is any non numeric non letter and non $ _ and # ? in str

Comment: I dont want to remove them but just test if there are in the variable.

Comment: and what about the $ _ and # ? they should be not rejected.

Answer (score -1):

Below is the code snippet of JavaScript. I think this will solve your purpose.

```
var format = /[@$_]+/;

if(format.test('abcd@$_')){
    alert("true");
    return true;
} else {
    alert("false");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Wrong language.